# how to reset dpkg completely

Tags: dpkg

Is there anyway I can reinstall `dpkg` and `apt-get` from ground up, and reset dependencies to the default one when ubuntu is installed. 
Iam also having a problem with `/va/lib/dpkg/available`
I reached a point where dependencies are totally in conflict
and I cant use almost any `apt` command.
I dont mind removing all apps but I need the files so,
im trying to fix this manually because I dont have the ubuntu cd and i am on a limited bandwidth connection.

I am trying to resolve all this in recovery mode while mounted in rw mode..
Any Sugguestions?

Answer (score 0):

The only **true** way to reset dependencies and installed packages is to reinstall - there's no easy way to 'reset' to factory standard settings - not easily, anyways.  (And then after the reinstall, update the system to get security updates and bug fixes)

Comment: How about explaining the not *so easy way* since you mentioned ?

Comment: @ItachiSama That was the nice way of saying "Almost impossible if you have made modifications to the packages installed over time."  The only real way to reset dependencies is a clean installation that resets the system back to the pristine state, and erase all data.  (Factory Resets in windows are just clean reinstalls of the factory image)